# Code intellisense for Javascript when function param is object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const _post = params => {
    instance
        .post(params.url, params.data)
        .then(response => {
            params.onSuccess(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            params.onFailure(error);
        });
};
```

So I have this helper code written by someone else in the team.
What I am looking for is when ever some tries to call this function, It should tell them that what properties it is expecting. Such as it is expecting three keys url, data, onSuccess, onFailure

How can we achieve that. I tried looking JS Doc specs but it only let us tell that the param is object like `@param {Object} param`

Comment: Wild guess, does destructuring the argument help?

Comment: See `@typedef` and `@type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
/**
 * some func.
 * @param {Object} params - an object.
 * @param {string} params.url - a url.
 * @param {Object} params.data - an object.
 * @param {Function} params.onSuccess .
 * @param {Function} params.onFailure .
 */
function _post(params){}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21716874)

Comment: @cse Check the question - this does indeed look like an attempt to answer, and it may even be the right answer.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for your attention. I think it would be better if there is an explanation/information also otherwise it should be posted as comment.